# How To Use Request.Querystring In SharePoint 2010 Application Page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, url, query-string

I have the following lines of code:

```
SPList thisList = oWeb.Lists[new Guid(Request.Url.QueryString).Get("List")];
SPListItem thisItem = thisList.GetItemById(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
```

But the Request.Url.QueryString does not resolve correctly.
I have included the following using statements:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Web;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
```

When I right click I usually get a "Resolve" menu option if I have forgotten to put in a usings statement at the top but that does not appear.

[image: Request QueryString Not Resolving]

How can I use Request to get the parameters passed into a SharePoint application page?

Comment: Looks like your application page is not deriving from `LayoutsPageBase`?

Comment: @NadeemYousuf my application page is deriving from LayoutsPageBase but I also tried deriving from System.Web.UI.Page with no progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```

Also make sure your page inherits from either LayoutPageBase or UnsecuredLayoutPageBase which are the base classes for application pages.